# How can I update a column in a table where all the values of another column start with "to "?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to do an `update` but limit it.  How can I `update` the table `phrase` and set the field `politeness` to the value of 1 for all rows where the column `english` starts with `"to "`.

Note there is a space after "to".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is to matching word start with "to" and one space after that.

For string matching you can use `LIKE` operator of SQL. It functions to match the string specified by condition.

```
LIKE 'to %'
```

It meanes all the string starting with 'to' and one space after that.
% denominate any character that follow.

**Query:**

```
UPDATE phrase
SET politeness = 1
WHERE english LIKE 'to %'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE phrase
SET politeness = 1
WHERE english like 'to %'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server's [SUBSTRING()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) function to check the first three characters of the `english` column before updating the `politeness` column.

```
UPDATE phrase
SET politeness = 1
WHERE SUBSTRING(english, 1, 2) = 'to '
```

In a massive hat tip to all the other answers which used `LIKE`, using `LIKE` is probably preferable in this case.  Since we are matching from the start of the `english` column, an index can be used.  However, using `SUBSTRING()` should preclude any chance of using an index.  So I would probably go with the other answers and do this:

```
UPDATE phrase
SET politeness = 1
WHERE english LIKE 'to %'
```

Answer (score 1):

try first with one:

```
select * from politeness where english like 'to %'
```

to be sure of records to modify...

if the result is what you want, i think (if i understood your question)

```
update phrase set politeness = 1 where english like 'to %'
```

hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one.

```
UPDATE phrase
SET politeness = 1
WHERE english like 'to %'
```